# Clear on Appearance for UITableViewController in xib?

Tags: uitableview, xib, xcode5, ios6.1

I am using XCode5.0 and iOS6.1. I don't want to clear the selection when the view appears, so I unchecked the option of 'Clear on Appearance' in the xib but that didn't make any difference.

[image]

I added the code programmatically in the code `self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;` 
and this doesn't clear the cell selection when I perform any action on the screen i.e. when I rotate the orientation.

Am I missing something here or isn't the 'Clear on Appearance' option working in XCode5.0?

Comment: Did you deselect it somewhere else?+

Comment: Nopes I cross checked it multiple times. Its the same xib which I am using for the controller class. Am looking if anybody else is facing the same issue in XCode 5?

Comment: See also: [same question but on storyboard instead of xib](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21296623/1402846).

Comment: As far as I can tell, this is a bug on Apple's part.  If you implement the setter on a derived class, it is always set to true.   And that's how I spent my morning!