# Is ios7 UITableViewController's Clear on Appearance broken (from Storyboard)?

Tags: ios, uitableview, cocoa-touch, uikit, uistoryboard

Using Storyboards in XCode5 for iOS7, I unchecked the "Clear on Appearance" checkbox for a UITableViewController. Using the version editor, I could see that the actual text in the file reacted accordingly (btw, is there a better way to see "source" of the storyboard?). But when I added

```
-(void) viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSLog(@"clear on appear %d", self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear);
}
```

It always showed as 1 (`YES`). Regardless of on or off in the storyboard. To get the desired affect, I had to add:

```
self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear= NO;
```

to that method. Did I misunderstand the way this was supposed to work? Or is it broken?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, seems like it is broken.

This works on `viewDidLoad`:

```
self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;
```

Comment: Thanks for confirming.

Comment: Still not fixed on iOS 8.

Comment: It works in iOS 8. Make sure your viewWillAppear has a call to super.

Comment: Still not fixed in iOS 9.2.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, looks like a [bug](http://www.openradar.me/26180465), at least as of iOS 9.3. You can use IB's User Defined Runtime Attributes if you don't want to fix it in code:

[image]